# с++ "морской бой"

Tags: c++

Загорелся сделать морской бой на с++ чисто для себя (с++ еще осваиваю). Сделал так чтоб программа ставила метку на нужных координатах. Вопрос такой: "Как сделать так, чтоб программа зпоминала прошлый "ход" и в следующий раз выписывала то место, где "ход" уже имел место быть".

Описание проблемы не лучшее, но я старался.
Сам код (надеюсь, правильно вставил на сайт)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void tablica(int a,int b,int c,int d, int x, int y){
    for (int i=0; i<b; i++){
        for (int z=0; z<a; z++){
            if (i==0){
                if (z==0) cout <<"%" <<setw(3);
                else {
                    cout << setw(3) <<char(c);
                    c++;
                }
            }
            else if (z==0) {
                cout << d << setw(3);
                d++;    
            }
            else if (z==x && i==y) cout << setw(3) << "X";
            else cout << setw(3) <<".";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int q,q1;
    do{
        cin >> q >> q1;
        if (q!=0 || q1!=0) tablica(10,10,65,1,q,q1);
    }while(q!=0 || q1!=0);
    return 0;

}
```

Работа программы:

[image: работа "программы"]

Comment: `cout <<"%" <<setw(3)`, а также `cout << d << setw(3);` -  `setw` **после** вывода выглядит странно. Не ошибка, но бессмысленное действие. Зачем?

Comment: Нужно создать двумерный массив и в каждом элементе хранить был в ту клетку ход или не было, а также есть ли в ней корабль.

Comment: @Эникейщик к проверке наличия корабля еще дойду, надо сначла хотябы закончить "расстановку". Спасибо за комментарий, буду разбираться!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void
tablica(const int a,const int b, char c, int d,
        const int x, const int y, const int oldX, const int oldY){
    cout << '%';
    for (int i=1; i<b; ++i) {
        cout << setw(3) << c;
        ++c;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < b; ++i) {
        cout << endl << d;
        ++d;
        for (int z=1; z<a; z++){
            if ( (z==x && i==y) || (z == oldX && i == oldY)) cout << setw(3) << 'X';
            else
                cout << setw(3) <<'.';
        }
    }
}


int main()
{   
    int q,q1;
    const int a = 10, b = 10, d = 1;
    char c = 'A';
    while (cin >> q >> q1 && (q!=0 || q1!=0) && q < a && q1 < b) {
          static int x = q, y = q1;
          tablica(a, b, c , d, x, y, q, q1);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Во первых в аргументах функции нужно указать какие аргументы не подлежат изменению, дальше вы в циклах делаете много сравнений. Чтобы цикл работал быстрее, нужно уменьшить их количество. Первая строка и столбец у вас всегда неизменяема, поэтому эти данные нужно выводить отдельно.

Не гарантировано, что целочисленное значение символа 'A' равно 65(в других реализациях может иметь другое значение), поэтому передайте в аргумент именно символ, тем более, что так нагляднее что есть этот аргумент.

Дальше: манипулятор  `setw(3)`  выделяет поле для текущего выводимого/вводимого обьекта, а не для предыдущего, поэтому  в  выражение, например: `cout <<"%" <<setw(3);`   `<<setw(3)` ничего не выполняет и совершенно лишнее.

В программе `do/while`  конструкция не нужна.  Без нее проще.

**Ответ на ваш вопрос:**

Чтобы хранить данные, введенные в функции или являющийся аргументами функции, и при этом вызывать функцию по циклу, нужно передать в аргументы функции статические обьекты такого же типа, для их инициализации старыми данными. Не гарантировано, что я хорошо обьяснил все, но программа вам поможет понять...

P.S.  По хорошему, просто вам нужен двумерный массив, а функция просто по заданному координату добавит метку

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно хранить состояния, это можно делать с помощью внешних переменных по отношению к функции(Передавать их по ссылке или указателю). Но я бы смотрел в строну ООП. Вам нужны сущности Ход, Список Ходов, Поле, Игрок, Игра(список неполный). Ваш код громоздок и сложен для понимания. Разбив свою игру на мелкие сущности и описав взаимодействия между ними, Вы его сможете упростить. PS Имена входных параметров не очень осмысленны, что тоже усложняет понимание.

Comment: Нужно учитывать, что  автор  только изучает язык, и чтобы просто выводить на консоль никакие сущности не нужны. Думаю, если же что то и нужно, при знании языка, то это ассоциативный массив или просто массив, в зависимости от того, что хотим иметь...